# Binding data to Gridview Header Template? In Asp.net

Tags: asp.net

In web application, I am trying to bind the Header Template of the gridivew, but i am not able to bind the data to gridview header.

```
   <asp:GridView ID ="grdInner" runat ="server" AutoGenerateColumns ="false" >
       <Columns >
          <asp:TemplateField >
             <HeaderTemplate >
          <asp:Label ID="lblHeader" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("title") %>'></asp:Label>     
              </HeaderTemplate>
              <ItemTemplate >
                 <asp:Label ID ="lblDesc" runat ="server" Text ='<%# Eval("description") %>'></asp:Label>
              </ItemTemplate>
          </asp:TemplateField> 
       </Columns>
     </asp:GridView>
```

Comment: You can't data bind to the Header because there is only one. You can only data bind to the repeating Item.

Answer (score 5):

Following code achieves the same things

```
<asp:GridView runat="server" ID="gridView" onrowdatabound="gridView_OnRowDataBound" AutoGenerateColumns="false">
<columns>
    <asp:TemplateField>
        <HeaderTemplate><asp:Label runat="server" ID="lblHeader"></asp:Label></HeaderTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateField>
</columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

You can set label text in OnRowDataBound event

```
 protected void gridView_OnRowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.Header)
            ((Label)e.Row.FindControl("lblHeader") as Label).Text = "Your Data here";
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way to do this that is fairly simple if you want to bind the DataTable column headers to the Gridview headers (for example, you are generating DataTables where the column names can be different and you want these dynamic names to be the GridView header column names).

```
DataTable dt = // Call your DataTable here.

    // Get your column names here.
    string nutrient = dt.Columns[2].ColumnName;
    string nutrient1 = dt.Columns[3].ColumnName;
    string nutrient2 = dt.Columns[4].ColumnName;
    string nutrient3 = dt.Columns[5].ColumnName;
    string nutrient4 = dt.Columns[6].ColumnName;
    string nutrient5 = dt.Columns[7].ColumnName;
    
    GridView1.DataSource = dt;
    GridView1.DataBind();

    if (GridView1.Rows.Count > 0)
    {
        GridView1.HeaderRow.Cells[2].Text = nutrient;
        GridView1.HeaderRow.Cells[3].Text = nutrient1; 
        GridView1.HeaderRow.Cells[4].Text = nutrient2;
        GridView1.HeaderRow.Cells[5].Text = nutrient3;
        GridView1.HeaderRow.Cells[6].Text = nutrient4;
        GridView1.HeaderRow.Cells[7].Text = nutrient5;            
    }
```

You can also do the same thing with the footer row using GridView1.FooterRow.Cells[x].Text = ...